# Searching using meta_query in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress to search some content with a few restrictions. Every time I save a post, I save in meta a related posts array.

Then I'm trying to search all posts which has a certain post as related, I have the following query. Selected post is an id to the post I'm looking for.

I checked `$selected_post` and it has values like the following one.

```
$selected_post = "25";
```

I added the meta value using the following instruction, I'm using `update_post_meta`. `$related_posts` contains an array of post ids, like the example below.

```
            update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'related_post', $related_posts );
```

**Query**

```
            $arg = array(
                'post_type'         => 'post',
                'posts_per_page'    => 5,
                'meta_query'        => array(
                    'relation'  => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key'       => 'related_post',
                        'value'     => array( $selected_post ),
                        'compare'   => 'IN',
                        'type'      => 'STRING'
                    ),
                ),
            );
```

I checked this meta in some of my current posts, and I have something like this.

```
'related_post' => array( '15', '25', '46' );
```

When I execute this query using `WP_Query` it always returns me an empty array. I think I need something more in the query to make this works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code is fine - you shouldn't have `'relation'  => 'OR'` there because you only have one condition in yuor meta_query, but it should still work. So it must be to do with the data itself. Have you confirmed that `$selected_post` has a valid, single value? How are you adding `related_post` (e.g. custom field. using add_post_meta. ACF) and what format is it? If you are just querying a single value, why not use `=` instead of `IN`?

Comment: @FluffyKitten First of all, thanks for the comment. Yes I checked that `$selected_post` has a single value. I will update my question and gives you the information you're asking for. I'm querying if my `$selected_post` is inside the array of related_posts, it's not a single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to query `related_posts` as if it was an array, but it actually gets serialised when its added to the database.

**Using WP_Query on serialized arrays**

If you were to add an array of post meta as follows:

```
$fruit_array = array( 'apple', 'orange', 'banana' );
update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fruit', $fruit_array );
```

...the value for `fruit` in the database would be:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:5:"apple";i:1;s:6:"orange";i:2;s:6:"banana";}
```

Therefore you need to use `LIKE` to search the serialised string for the value you are looking for.

For the above example, your `$args` would be something like:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'    => 5,
    'meta_query'    => array(
             array(
                   'key'      => 'fruit',
                   'value'    => 'apple',
                   'compare'  => 'LIKE',
            ),
    )
);
```

**Search for numbers/post ids**

In your case, this is complicated by the fact that you are using post ids. Post ids or numbers aren't an issue specifically, but the problem is that `LIKE` will also return partial matches, so a query for `14` would also return `141`, `1455` etc.

Based on the structure of the serialised string, I believe the following should work:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'    => 5,
    'meta_query'    => array(
             array(
                   'key'      => 'related_post',
                   'value'    => '"25"', /* include the double quotes in the search value */
                   'compare'  => 'LIKE',
            ),
    )
);
```

As the values in the serialised string becomes `"25";` including the double quotes in the value you want to search for should work.